# How to get SWF activity information for a given workflow execution using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-swf

When looking at the SWF console on Amazon AWS, you can view closed workflow executions' histories. In the history, you can see all the activities that were called and their inputs and outputs.

I haven't been able to figure out how to access this activity information using boto 2. I am able to get the history of a workflow, but it resembles the "Events" tab of the SWF console and not the "Activities" tab. For example, it doesn't contain the output of any activities.

Here is the code I've used to get to where I am:

```python
domain = boto.swf.layer2.Domain(name=swf_domain, 
                                aws_access_key_id=<id>, 
                                aws_secret_access_key=<secret>)

close_oldest_date = int((datetime.utcnow() - 
                         timedelta(days=LOOKBACK_DAYS)).timestamp())
execution = domain.executions(closed=True,
                              close_status='COMPLETED',
                              maximum_page_size=1,
                              close_oldest_date=close_oldest_date)[0]

print(execution.history())
```

Is there a way to access the completed activities' inputs, outputs, and other information using boto 2? Possibly using boto 3?

Comment: hey Brian Schlenker :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

History contains complete information about activity execution.

[ActivityTaskScheduled](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_ActivityTaskScheduledEventAttributes.html) contains input of an activity.

[ActivityTaskStarted](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_ActivityTaskStartedEventAttributes.html) contains identity of a worker (usually host:pid

[ActivityTaskCompleted](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_ActivityTaskCompletedEventAttributes.html) contains activity output.

[ActivityTaskFailed](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_ActivityTaskFailedEventAttributes.html) contains failure information

Consult [API Referece](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/Welcome.html) to get full information about available events and their meaning.

Comment: Could you comment why you didn't like the correct answer?

Comment: this answer is ok, you need to parse the data in "history"